# Showing $F(U) =\operatorname{Hom}(V,U)$ and $G(U)=V \otimes U$ are adjoint functors

Tags: category-theory

Following Christian Kassel's "Quantum Groups" page 280

Let for a fixed vector space $V$ $F,G$ be functors from the category of vector spaces (which we will call $A$) to itself defind by: $$F(U) = \operatorname{Hom}(V,U)$$ $$G(U)=V \otimes U$$

The natural transformation $\operatorname{Hom}(U \otimes V,W) \cong \operatorname{Hom}(U,\operatorname{Hom}(V,W))$ shows that $G$ is a left adjoint functor to $F$

---

So, since $G$ is left adjoint functor to $F$ we have natural transformations $$\nu\colon\operatorname{id}_A \rightarrow FG$$ $$\theta\colon GF \rightarrow\operatorname{id}_A$$

such that the compositions

$$F(V) \rightarrow^{\nu(F(V))} FGF(V) \rightarrow^{F(\theta(V))} F(V)$$

and

$$G(W) \rightarrow^{G\nu(W)} GFG(W) \rightarrow^{(\theta(G(W))} F(V)$$

act as the identity for all vector spaces $V$

---

Can somebody show me how to define $\nu$ and $\theta$ and help me understand why the compositions are acting as the identity on every vector space? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: $\nu$ and $\theta$ are "natural transformations", not "natural isomorphisms".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\Hom}{Hom}$When it comes to adjoint functors, the natural transformations involved are often defined in the only possible way you could define them, given very little information that you have.

Starting with the unit $\nu$, for any vector space $U$, we need to produce a linear map $$\nu_U\colon U\to \Hom(V,V\otimes U).$$
$\nu_U$ should take a vector $u\in U$ and produce a linear map $\nu_U(u)\colon V\to V\otimes U$. So, given vector $v\in V$, we know that $\nu_U(u)(v)$ should be a vector in $V\otimes U$. There is really only one thing that we can do and that is to define $\nu_U(u)(v) = v\otimes u$. I prefer to write it like this:

\begin{align}
U &\to \Hom(\,V\ , \,V\otimes U\,)\\
u &\mapsto \quad\quad\,(v\mapsto v\otimes u)
\end{align}

I leave to you to verify that $\nu_U$ and $\nu_U(u)$ are linear maps and that $\nu$ is natural.

Similarly, to define counit $\theta$, for every vector space $U$, we need to produce a linear map
$$\theta_U\colon V\otimes\Hom(V,U)\to U.$$
We can easily define linear maps on simple tensors (by the universal property of tensor product), so given $v\in V$ and $A\colon V\to U$, $\theta_U(v\otimes A)$ should be a vector in $U$. But really, given $A$ and $v$, there is only one way to produce a vector in $U$ and that is to evaluate $A$ at $v$. Thus, $\theta_U(v\otimes A) = Av$ and $\theta_U$ is just evaluation map. (This shows up quite often!) I prefer to write it like this:
\begin{align}
V\otimes \Hom(V,U) & \to U\\
v\otimes  A        &\mapsto Av
\end{align}
I leave to you to show that $\theta_U$ is indeed well defined and $\theta$ is natural.
That the compositions are identities is very straightforward to check.

Finally, a personal remark. I find it quite upsetting that $G$ is left and $F$ is right adjoint and not the other way around.

Comment: Thanks man!! Great response!

Comment: You call $\nu$ the unit and $\theta$ the counit... Is that because these natural transformations generalize the unit and counit concepts in an algebra and coalgebra?

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa, you are welcome. For every adjunction $L\dashv R$, $RL$ is a monad (monoid object in the category of endofunctors) and the unit of the adjunction is the unit of the monad. Dually, $LR$ is comonad (comonoid in the category of endofunctors) and the counit of the adjunction is the counit of the comonad.

Comment: Man... Category theory sounds like it gets pretty bonkers... amazing to think that it actually brings clarity into ideas once the mathematics gets advanced enough

Comment: For me, already the explication of the (Cartan-Eilenberg?) natural adjunction/isomorphism ${\mathrm Hom}(X\otimes Y,Z)\approx {\mathrm Hom}(X, {\mathrm Hom}(Y,Z))$ makes the rest of it inevitable.

Comment: @paul garrett, yes, that's true. I'm sure you are aware of this, but let me type it out for an interested reader. In general, if $L\dashv R$ and $\Phi_{X,Y}\colon\operatorname{Hom}(LX,Y)\to\operatorname{Hom}(X,RY)$ is a natural isomorphism, the unit and the counit are given by $\eta_X=\Phi_{X,LX}(id_{LX})$ and $\varepsilon_Y=\Phi^{-1}_{RY,Y}(id_{RY})$. Conversely, $\Phi_{X,Y}(f)=Rf\circ\eta_X$ and $\Phi^{-1}_{X,Y}(g)=\varepsilon_Y\circ Lg$ defines $\Phi$ and $\Phi^{-1}$. I guess it's a matter of taste or particular use you have in mind which you might prefer.